# Rails ::module_name vs module_name and modules being splitted between several files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

Let's say I have a parser module (`parser.rb`) inside `app/lib`:

```
module Parsers
    class XMLParser
        def self.parse
            "Parsing XML...."
        end
    end

    class TXTParser
        def self.parse
            "Parsing TXT...."
        end
    end
end
```

I've seen some people calling the classes like this:

```
@parse_xml = ::Parsers::XMLParser.parse
@parse_txt = ::Parsers::TXTParser.parse
```

Instead of:

```
@parse_xml = Parsers::XMLParser.parse
@parse_txt = Parsers::TXTParser.parse
```

Both ways work, so what's the difference? Also, I've seen cases where a module is split in several files, for example:

Inside `app/lib/parsers/xml_parser.rb`:

```
module Parsers
    class XMLParser
        def self.parse
            "Parsing XML...."
        end
    end
end
```

And inside `app/lib/parsers/txt_parser.rb`:

```
module Parsers
    class TXTParser
        def self.parse
            "Parsing XML...."
        end
    end
end
```

Is there any difference (besides the obvious... which is smaller files) between both options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both ways work, so what's the difference? Also, I've seen cases where a module is split in several files, for example:

`::` allows you to target root level scopes.  By default ruby searches up the current scope tree that you're in.  I know that sounds vague, but an example will make this clear:

```
module A
  module B
    def self.test
      A::C.test
      D::B.test
      ::D::B.test
    end
  end

  module C
    def self.test
      p "calling A::C"
    end
  end

  module D
    module B
      def self.test
        p "calling A::D::B"
      end
    end
  end
end

module D
  module B
    def self.test
      p "calling D::B"
    end
  end
end

A::B::test
```

This will print:

```
"calling A::C"
"calling A::D::B"
"calling D::B"
```

> Is there any difference (besides the obvious... which is smaller files) between both options?

Both of those will work the same.  Typically, in ruby, you do one class definition per file, with the file named after the class.  So you'll more often see the two file version, and I'd recommend that for style, but it doesn't matter.